# Unable to import components automatically after importing common angular2 module

Tags: angular, module, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I have created a common module and two other modules that use the common module. I have exported some components from the common module and have imported the common module in both the other component. But when I try using the component in the routes for the two modules I cannot use it automatically and have to import the component explicitly from the path of common module. This is posing a issue with module independenc-y. How do I resolve this?

```
CommonsModule --> UsersModule (URouting)
CommonsModule --> ReportingModule (RRouting)
```

I do not have access to the exported components inside URouting and RRouting until I get them from the CommonsModule path explicitly. I have exported the components from CommonsModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoginCommonComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './components/error/error.component';
import { AutocompleteComponent } from './components/autocomplete/autocomplete.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginCommonComponent, ErrorComponent, AutocompleteComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [LoginCommonComponent, ErrorComponent, AutocompleteComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppCommonsModule { }
```

Users Module

importing in module

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppCommonsModule,
    adminrouting
  ],
```

In routes I have to do something like this:

```
import {UsersComponent} from '../components/main/main.component';
import {LoginComponent} from '../components/login/login.component'
import {ErrorComponent} from '../../commons/components/error/error.component';

const usersRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'shop', component: UsersComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
        {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        {path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}
    ] }
];
```

This is my problem
    `import {ErrorComponent} from '../../commons/components/error/error.component';`

should I be necessarily doing this? What other options do I have? I am creating a common module that should be allowed automatically. Do you think I should create it as a module and map it in systemjs.config?

Comment: Does the common NgModule enumerate them under both `declarations` and `exports`?

Comment: Yes Aluan, it does. Edited the question again for the comment

Comment: That looks like it should work... how are you in importing it?

Comment: Added the complete codes. should I be necessarily doing this import in routes directly? What other options do I have? I am creating a common module that should be allowed automatically. Do you think I should create it as a module and map it in systemjs.config which is not what I am doing?

Comment: `NgModule` and ES Modules are orthogonal. Non-angular-specific tools have no knowledge of them so it makes no difference. SystemJS and TypeScript are two tools that work with ES Modules, so no it is unrelated. You cannot automatically provide an `NgModule` you need to list it as an import in the `NgModule`s that use it either directly or transitively.

Comment: Ok. I understood the second answer. In case of my first question does that mean that I have to import the components compulsorily from the path in the routes module and there is no other option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136505/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-gary).